# Page Breaks After shown.bs.modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I use some modal in a page, but whenever I open modals (or triggering shown.bs.modal event) width of whole page gets a little bit short. This is what happens:

I click "İletişim" element:
[image]

I see it is broken in background:
[image]

This happens when I do it a couple of times:
[image]

Those are the codes I used:

```
<div id="contact-dialog" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Mesaj Gönder</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Test</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Gönder</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Vazgeç</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="sent-dialog" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Gönderildi</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Mesaj Gönderildi.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Tamam</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#contact-dialog").on("hidden.bs.modal", function(){
        $("#sent-dialog").modal("show");
    });
});
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code and modal http://jsfiddle.net/pe86f7pn/ there must be something else, are you using any animation css?

Comment: Well, appearently not. However, I used Opera to view the page. There's no problem with Firefox. It seems it's a problem with the renderer of Opera. I now wonder if it does the same in Chrome since current Opera has Chromium core inside.

Comment: I don't have Opera but i checked in firefox and chrome, both updated to latest versions and there is no problem

Comment: Thnaks again. I'll report this issue to Opera though.

Comment: @ErayErdin Can you check one thing, Try to see if sent-dialog have parent width 100% and in root of document

Comment: @GuptaAnirudha, I think it has nothing to do with the parent width 100%, see here http://jsfiddle.net/pe86f7pn/1/ open 2nd modal and see the modal not in center, in opera may be the modal `transform` property not rendering properly.

Comment: @ErayErdin check the fiddle in above comment, you can adjust the modal `transform` property and force it to open at right place with `!important` rule, just change the `translateX(-25%)` to `translateX(0%)`

Comment: I tested it now. That does not work either. :(

Comment: @ErayErdin I added this `.modalout` to 2nd modal here `<div id="sent-dialog" class="modal fade modalout" role="dialog">` so with `important` rule it override the default modal `transform`

Comment: Now that did work dude, thanks. Maybe you should write this as answer, not a comment. :)

Comment: @ErayErdin answer added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussion with OP;

First thing, I'm not able to reproduce the problem with provided code in question when modals open in latest version of `firefox`, `chrome` and `opera` using `jQuery 2.1.0` and bootstrap version `3.0.0` up-to `3.3.5`

[Fiddle (without problem)](http://jsfiddle.net/pe86f7pn/)

So my guess is that there is a `selector` has `transform` property which causing the issue and forcing the modal not open at it's default position.

e.g; If I add custom `transform: translateX(-25%) translateY(0%);` property which override the modal default `transform` property, the modal will show exactly at the position shown in snapshot in question.

[Fiddle (problem reproduced)](http://jsfiddle.net/pe86f7pn/2/)

So solution or more likely hack is to create a custom selector `defaultposition`, add it in modal HTML, set default modal `transform: translateX(0%) translateY(5%);` properties and just to be on safe side, add `!important` rule too.

HTML

```
<div id="contact-dialog" class="modal fade defaultposition" role="dialog">
```

CSS

```
.defaultposition {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0%) translateY(5%) !important;
    -moz-transform: translateX(0%) translateY(5%) !important;
    -ms-transform: translateX(0%) translateY(5%) !important;
    transform: translateX(0%) translateY(5%) !important;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pe86f7pn/4/)

So whatever causing the problem and not letting modal to show at it's default position will be overridden and modal will show at it's default position.